# meal, created = Meal.objects.get_or_create(name=meal_data.get('name', '')) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, api, sqlite, django-rest-framework

this is django rest_framework api I created this api for restourant. This is menu api . I want to save menu.json's data to my database, but I could not. Can you give any advice to save json data to my models. I got this error:

```
      File "C:\Users\OSMAN MERT\Desktop\menu\menu_core\api\models.py", line 36, in store_json_data
        meal, created = Meal.objects.get_or_create(name=meal_data.get('name', ''))
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How can I solve it? I need your help?

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    import json
    # Create your models here.
    
    class Meal(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        is_vegetarian = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_vegan = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    class Ingredient(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        groups = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    class Option(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        quality = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        price = models.FloatField()
        per_amount = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    class MealIngredient(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
        meal = models.ForeignKey(Meal, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    
    
    
    path = r"C:\Users\OSMAN MERT\Desktop\menu\menu_core\menu.json"
    
    def store_json_data(json_data):
        for meal_data in json_data:
            meal, created = Meal.objects.get_or_create(name=meal_data.get('name', ''))
            if not created:
                meal.is_vegetarian = meal_data.get('is_vegetarian', False)
                meal.is_vegan = meal_data.get('is_vegan', False)
                meal.save()
            for ingredient_data in meal_data.get('ingredients', []):
                ingredient, _ = Ingredient.objects.get_or_create(name=ingredient_data.get('name', ''), meal=meal)
                for option_data in ingredient_data.get('options', []):
                    option, _ = Option.objects.get_or_create(quality=option_data.get('quality', ''), ingredient=ingredient)
                    option.price = option_data.get('price', 0)
                    option.save()
    
    def load_json_file(path):
        with open(path) as json_file:
            json_data = json.load(json_file)
            store_json_data(json_data)
    
    load_json_file(path)
```

This is some data from menu.json not all code include there.
menu.json

```
    {
    "meals": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Rice and chicken bowl",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Rice", "quantity": 120, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Chicken", "quantity": 85, "quantity_type": "gram" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Pasta with marinara sauce and vegetables",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Pasta", "quantity": 115, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          {
            "name": "Marinara sauce",
            "quantity": 120,
            "quantity_type": "millilitre"
          },
          { "name": "Vegetables", "quantity": 240, "quantity_type": "gram" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Grilled chicken with roasted vegetables",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Chicken", "quantity": 85, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Vegetables", "quantity": 240, "quantity_type": "gram" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Beef stir-fry with rice",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Beef", "quantity": 115, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Rice", "quantity": 120, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Vegetables", "quantity": 240, "quantity_type": "gram" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Pork chops with mashed potatoes and gravy",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Pork chops", "quantity": 115, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          {
            "name": "Mashed potatoes",
            "quantity": 120,
            "quantity_type": "gram"
          },
          { "name": "Gravy", "quantity": 120, "quantity_type": "millilitre" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "Grilled salmon with roasted asparagus",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Salmon", "quantity": 85, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Asparagus", "quantity": 240, "quantity_type": "gram" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Shrimp scampi with linguine",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Shrimp", "quantity": 115, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Linguine", "quantity": 115, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Butter", "quantity": 10, "quantity_type": "millilitre" },
          { "name": "Garlic", "quantity": 10, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "White wine", "quantity": 60, "quantity_type": "millilitre" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "name": "Vegetarian stir-fry with tofu",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Tofu", "quantity": 115, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Rice", "quantity": 120, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Vegetables", "quantity": 240, "quantity_type": "gram" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "Fruit salad with mixed berries and yogurt",
        "ingredients": [
          { "name": "Mixed berries", "quantity": 240, "quantity_type": "gram" },
          { "name": "Yogurt", "quantity": 120, "quantity_type": "millilitre" }
        ]
      }
    ],
  
    "ingredients": [
      {
        "name": "Rice",
        "groups": ["vegan", "vegetarian"],
        "options": [
          {
            "name": "Long grain white rice",
            "quality": "high",
            "price": 3,
            "per_amount": "kilogram"
          },
          {
            "name": "Medium grain brown rice",
            "quality": "medium",
            "price": 2,
            "per_amount": "kilogram"
          },
          {
            "name": "Quick cooking white rice",
            "quality": "low",
            "price": 1.5,
            "per_amount": "kilogram"
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: can you print `meal_data `? This error say meal_data is string and `meal_data.get('name', '')) ` throw error?

Comment: I tried but it throw same error

Comment: what value of `meal_data` show below line `for meal_data in json_data:`? Or you can edit full file menu.json for debug?

Comment: ı try to travel menu.json for each meal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing is that you are not [looping correctly](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques) through the dictionary (You are trying to access `name` attribute inside the `key` value which is a string). You can either:

```
def store_json_data(json_data):
    for key, meal_data in json_data.items():
        if key == 'meals':
            for meal in meal_data:
                print(meal.get('name', ''))

        if key == 'ingredients':
            for ingredient in meal_data:
                ...
```

Or, instead of looping through the dictionary `key:value pair`, access the list value manually and then loop through it:

```
def store_json_data(json_data):
    meals = json_data.get("meals")
    ingredients = json_data["ingredients"]

    for meal in meals:
        print(meal.get('name', ''))

    for ingredient in ingredients:
        ...
```

That being said, what you are trying to do will not work, since when you [makemigrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/django-admin/#makemigrations) for the first time, database tables are not yet created and will raise an `OperationalError`.

I would suggest using [post_migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#post-migrate) signal to populate your tables.

Comment: thanks ı got idea but I wanna ask to in one field ı have array how can ı store this array to my models.  "ingredients": [
      {
        "name": "Rice",
        "groups": ["vegan", "vegetarian"] } ] one example.

Comment: You can either have another model to associate `ingredients` with `groups` (e.g. `IngredientGroup` which I recommend). Or, if you want to keep the current format using `CharField` it is possible to store in a `csv` format for example and post process that data when reading the field, although remember that the later solution has a character limit.

Comment: okey but as you can see my database there is separete file for this how can ı do that can you chech my database design. Thank you for helping. :))

Comment: Related to design. The main issue is that you are missing [extra fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) in your many-to-many relation at `MealIngredient` (namely `quantity` and `quantity_type` ) and it is also improperly configured, there is an example in the link. While the relation between `ingredient` and `IngredientGroup` would be a [many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

Comment: Also, you can get rid of `id` fields since Django does that [automatically](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)

Answer (score 0):

first, your `menu.json` you upload incorrect format. Missing some character.

Assum you have correct json like you upload to variable `json_data`

Error you show mean `meal_data` you get is string. And it can not use attribute `get`.

Try update like this for correct get every meal in json. `meal_data` become dict and can use `get`

```
    for meal_data in json_data.get("meals"):
        meal, created = Meal.objects.get_or_create(name=meal_data.get('name', ''))
```